# Is there a way to use fontello ttf icons in Windows Phone 8?

Tags: windows-phone-8, fonts

I need to use ttf for some icons in my Win8 phone project. I did a research but couldn't find any resources. Is there a way to achieve this?

```
<TextBlock x:Name="textBlock" Text="\uE82E" FontFamily="/fontello.ttf#fontello" />
```

[image]

[image]

Custom Font Runtime

```
TextBlock t = new TextBlock();
FontFamily ff = new FontFamily("/Fonts/fontello.ttf#fontello");
t.FontFamily = ff;
t.Text = "&#xE821";
```

Comment: So you want [to use a custom font on Windows Phone](http://www.geekchamp.com/news/using-custom-fonts-in-windows-phone-apps)?

Comment: Nope, it's not displaying icons.

Comment: <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock" Text="\uE82E" FontFamily="/fontello.ttf#fontello" />

Comment: Have you included the font at that location in your project, with the relevant build action?

Comment: Yes, I did. You can check the image I just uploaded.

Comment: And is the font family name "fontello"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify the Unicode value in this way:

XAML:

```
<TextBlock x:Name="textBlock" Text="&#xE82E;" FontFamily="fontello.ttf#fontello" />
```

Code behind:

```
textBlock.FontFamily = new FontFamily("fontello.ttf#fontello");
textBlock.Text = "\uE82E";
```

Comment: Abhishek, it displays the icons in xaml design, however, it does not display on emulator. Do you know why?

Comment: You need to set the build action of the .ttf file as Content. By default it takes build action value of None. From the Solution Explorer, right click on the .ttf file, select Properties and set build action as Content.

Comment: Sorry, Apperantly, it changed again. Probably, I deleted and added the font again without setting content. Thank you, again.=)

Comment: Hi, Abhishek! I am sorry to bother you a lot but I have one more question. I am having hard time to set the same custom font icon in runtime. Could you please check my edited question, please?

Comment: The format `&#xXXXX;` works in XAML. In code behind you need to write in `\uXXXX` format. So use `t.Text = "\uE821";`. I have updated the original answer as well.